# preg_match / word boundery only works to a limited extent

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, preg-match, explode

I would like to compare a text from its textarea with a come-separated keyword list and trigger a specific action if one or more hits are found.
Unfortunately, my script only works to a limited extent and triggers my function even if a character string, e.g. B. "ee" or "work" is identified.

Example for the keyword list:
"FREE Shipping,times,50% OFF,Backpack,Marketing,working,Owner,CEO"

Example of a text from the textarea:
"it seems that the function is not working correctly"

```
$messageTemp = explode(",",$GLOBALS['Message']);

foreach ($messageTemp as $valueK) {
if (preg_match("~\b(.+)$valueK\b~",$GLOBALS['Keyword']) !== 0 ) {
    $GLOBALS['Key'] = 1;
    };
};
```

I'm grateful for every hint

Comment: for this kind of question please provide input and expected output examples. Also, you can play with regex patterns here https://www.regexpal.com/ to see better visualisation

Answer (score 0):

To put an arbitrary string inside reg exp you have to escape it first. Also, I added `i`gnore case option. And removed the (.+) part.

```
foreach ($messageTemp as $valueK) {
    $reg ="~\b".preg_quote($valueK, '/')."\b~i";
    if (preg_match($reg, $keyword) !== 0) {
        $GLOBALS['Key'] = 1;
    }
}
```